# Does Hyper-V Server R2 require a domain to use the new features?

Tags: domain, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, workgroup

Simple question that I've yet to find a simple answer for: do you need a domain in order to use the new features in Hyper-V Server 2008 R2? Using the Remote Server Administration tools? Using SCVMM?

All the demos and documentation of live migration, cluster shared volumes, & failover clustering have used a domain, but have not explicitly said it was requried. Can these features be used within a workgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Clustering requires a domain so I would have to say yes you need a domain.